# Replacing all instances of char 1 with char 2 while replacing all instances of char 2 with char 1 in a string

Tags: python, string

In Python, I have a string of the form "1343214324" - all characters are either "1", "2", "3", or "4". I am trying to replace all instances of "1" with "3", all instances of "3" with "1", all instances of "2" with "4", and all instances of "4" with "2". If I just used replace, I would get a string of all "1"s and "2"s. In the above, it should return "3121432142".

Right now, I am simply iterating through the characters in the string and appending to another string.

```py
newString = ""
for ch in string:
    ch = string[j]
    if ch == "1":
        newString += "3"
    elif ch == "2":
        newString += "4"
    elif ch == "3":
        newString += "1"
    else:
        newString += "2"
```

Although this works, I feel like it is not very pythonic and could even be more efficient. Is there a more pythonic way of doing the above?

Comment: Use a `dict` to map the key value pairs instead.

Comment: Interesting - I didn't think of that. Should I delete my question since it is a duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

Use `dict` with `str.join`:

```
s = "1343214324"
d = {'1': '3', '3': '1', '2': '4', '4': '2'}
''.join([d[i] for i in s])
```

Output:

```
'3121432142'
```